# Re-initializing Angular application on a specific event: Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular 5 for building a web application and would like to know if I can re-initialize the entire application OR use something like:

```
ApplicationRef.tick();
```

to execute all the changes that happens after a specific event. The event is my scenario is authentication token renewal, because for some reason my application's change detection starts breaking unless I run each action inside

```
NgZone.run()
```

(I'm using ADAL for authentication in case anybody is interested), but when the token is renewed (using a hidden iframe) the application change detection, routing, etc starts breaking. But when the page is refreshed it starts working perfectly fine till the next time token expires and ADAL has to create an iFrame to renew the token. So I was thinking if at least I could re-initialize the application after the token is renewed so that user doesn't have to refresh the application manually (till I find a more solid solution).

Answer (score 0):

It's mandatory, if you are calling any third party API or executing third party library Codes. We need to manually call ngzone.run(), which will internally call ApplicationRef.tick() to notify angular to perform change detection from Application root component to the child component (i.e whole application).

```
ngZone.run(()=>{
  // Adal callback Function
});
```

If you are need to trigger change detection only to the current component and their childrens (not whole application). You can use any one option.

```
1) setTimeout(()=>{}, 0);

2) this.cdr.detectChanges();

3) For Components with OnPush Change Detection Stratergy, you can call this.cdr.markForCheck() inside setTimeout();

   setTimeout(()=>{
     this.cdr.markForCheck();
   }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the change detection explictly like below.

```
 constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    this.someEvents.subscribe((data) => {

    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
   } );
}
```

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef